# dotnet error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/

Tags: .net-core, fedora

**Steps to reproduce**

dotnet build or dotnet run

**Expected behavior**

Run or Build app

**Actual Behavior**

```
Getting ready...
The template "ASP.NET Core with Angular" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on /home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/b19d3901039706ea82571abad7c98ec690508d4b' for operations on '/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/obj/salao.csproj.nuget.cache'. This may mean that a different user or administator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/b19d3901039706ea82571abad7c98ec690508d4b' will allow NuGet to continue. [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]

Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

**Environment Data**

dotnet --info

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version: 3.1.101
Commit: b377529961

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: fedora
OS Version: 31
OS Platform: Linux
RID: fedora.31-x64
Base Path: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/

Host (useful for support):
Version: 3.1.1
Commit: a1388f194c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
3.1.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**Obs**

Tried Fixes put in dotnet restore, but I received the same error.

Did not have this problem with dotnet sdk 2.0.

Comment: Did you see the part about "This may mean that a different user or administator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/b19d3901039706ea82571abad7c98ec690508d4b' will allow NuGet to continue". Did you try that?

Comment: Well..  I did try find the path, but I didn't find anywhere. 

I did look at /var, /home e etc, but I didn't find.

Comment: The path is literally under `/tmp` (which is another top-level directory like `/var` and `/home`): `/tmp/NuGetScratch/`.

Comment: @OmairMajid please, see the post below.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4173

Comment: On your system, will the environment variable `TMPDIR` be used as `Path.GetTempPath`?  If so, could you set it to something writeable by the executing user?  For example, if `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set, `export TMPDIR=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/tmp;mkdir -p ${TMPDIR}`.

Comment: Ok @rickhg12hs, I fixed this.  And now I've been receive the next error: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "dotnet" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (40): Too many levels of symbolic links [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed that bug with commands below:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp/NuGetScratch/
mkdir -p ${TMPDIR}
```

but, I've been receive the other error and I opened other question post: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773537/dotner-core-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links)

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the problem was caused by ownership of the "lock file" (in Linux).
I was running `dotnet build` under my user (without sudo) but my project was created using `sudo`.

**Option A)**
Use sudo again

```
sudo dotnet build
```

**Option B)**
Change /tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/ ownership:

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user> /tmp/NuGetScratch/
```

Then, the user can run `dotnet build` without sudo.

Comment: `sudo dotnet clean` will definitely help if you previously ran `dotnet build` under the wrong user

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error in my `Visual Studio 2022` when I was trying to build my new console project.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Unable to obtain
> lock file access on for operations on 'NuGet.Config'. This may mean
> that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that
> this process does not have permission to access it. If no other
> process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean
> that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock
> file, in this case removing the file will allow NuGet to continue.

The very easy fix you can do is to open your `Visual Studio` as an administrator and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

@Omair Majid, see:

```
[limup@localhost tmp]$ ll -a
total 12
drwxrwxrwt. 22 root  root   480 Jan 15 16:59 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root  root  4096 Jan 10 18:51 ..
drwx------.  2 limup limup   60 Jan 15 16:54 .esd-1000
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root  root    40 Jan 15 16:49 .font-unix
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:54 .ICE-unix
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-adb.service-WzMSag
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-chronyd.service-Rw6V8i
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:50 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-colord.service-9QFuBh
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-dbus-broker.service-DqpFAf
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:54 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-fwupd.service-eBNBLh
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:54 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-geoclue.service-O6YLYg
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-ModemManager.service-hHCfHf
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-rtkit-daemon.service-3A8e9f
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-switcheroo-control.service-zSjrXg
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:49 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-systemd-logind.service-ohP23f
drwx------.  3 root  root    60 Jan 15 16:50 systemd-private-5f8b1b99edb949b1864fa2e580380675-upower.service-kMAiIg
drwx------.  2 limup limup   40 Jan 15 16:58 Temp-31248c7a-04ad-429c-ab49-4c2ed74a1986
drwx------.  2 limup limup   40 Jan 15 16:58 Temp-8fa994cb-0334-4cf9-886d-103347596108
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root  root    40 Jan 15 16:49 .Test-unix
drwx------.  2 limup limup   40 Jan 15 17:00 tracker-extract-files.1000
-r--r--r--.  1 limup limup   11 Jan 15 16:54 .X0-lock
-r--------.  1 gdm   gdm     11 Jan 15 16:50 .X1024-lock
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root  root    80 Jan 15 16:54 .X11-unix
drwxrwxrwt.  2 root  root    40 Jan 15 16:49 .XIM-unix
```