# dotner core: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: linux, .net-core, fedora

I'm trying build the code of dotnet core on linux, but I've been receive the next error:

```
[limup@localhost salao]$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 67.43 ms for /home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "dotnet" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (40): Too many levels of symbolic links [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec) [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tasks.DotNetToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(99,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [/home/limup/Documents/Projetos/Limup/salao/salao.csproj]
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

**Environment Data**

```
[limup@localhost salao]$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.101
 Commit:    b377529961

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     fedora
 OS Version:  31
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         fedora.31-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.1
  Commit:  a1388f194c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**OBS**

Tried Fixes put in dotnet restore, but I received the same error.

Did not have this problem with dotnet sdk 2.0.

Comment: Are there any useful output notifications if you increase the verbosity or logging options of `dotnet build`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response.

I found the solve in other post: [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d82e7f88-6a12-4ab8-899a-633c500f0793/dotner-core-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links?forum=netfxbcl)