# Unable to obtain lock file access (Dotnet CLI)

Tags: c#, bash, .net-core, nuget

I use Dev Containers to attach to a container and debug. And it was working just fine.

Recently however it shows this error when I hit F5 or run `dotnet build` from VS Code's terminal:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/NuGet.targets(132,5): error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/fcd2970c0c875310ff5855562ac5f3954170bddb' for operations on '/Crm/AdminApi/obj/project.nuget.cache'. This may mean that a different user or administrator is holding this lock and that this process does not have permission to access it. If no other process is currently performing an operation on this file it may mean that an earlier NuGet process crashed and left an inaccessible lock file, in this case removing the file '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/fcd2970c0c875310ff5855562ac5f3954170bddb' will allow NuGet to continue. [/Crm/AdminApi/Api.csproj]

And it shows the above message after trying to re-install every dependency, while NuGet has cached those dependencies already.

It works if:

1- I open a `root` bash using `docker exec -it container_name bash` and run `dotnet build`
2- I open a non root bash, and simply run `sudo dotnet build`
3- I open a VS Code termianl (which shows `vscode` as the user) and run `sudo dotnet build`

I tried `sudo chown -R vscode:vscode /tmp/NuGetScratch/` as mentioned in [dotnet error : Unable to obtain lock file access on '/tmp/NuGetScratch/lock/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756017/dotnet-error-unable-to-obtain-lock-file-access-on-tmp-nugetscratch-lock) and [here](https://medium.com/codebase/unable-to-obtain-lock-file-access-dotnet-cli-3bd313a5009c), but that did not change anything. I then tried `sudo chmod -R 777 /tmp/NuGetScratch` and again no results. I even verified that the owner is changed using `ls /tmp -lah | grep NuGet` and this is the results:

> drwxrwxrwx 1 vscode vscode 4.0K Feb  9 10:43 NuGetScratch

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This was recently logged as an issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12420

Possible workarounds listed from https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12420#issuecomment-1423774814:

1. Run `dotnet nuget locals temp -c` to clear the /tmp/NuGetScratch (If there is a sticky bit in /tmp permissions then it won't work)
2. Set environment variable `NUGET_ConcurrencyUtils_DeleteOnClose` to 1 before running restore, so the lock files will be cleared after restore (This change is only available in NuGet 6.2 and above, probably .NET 7 preview6 and above)
3. Set environment variable `NUGET_SCRATCH` to a path. This variable will override the default temp folder. But it's only applied to NuGet version 6.2 and later, probably .NET 7 preview6 and above).